# Remove MongoDB table elements via node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am populating my db (--modulus.io) everytime I run the server, in my model, since that gets called. However, I am unable to remove the contents of the table right before I populate, so I get duplicate contents.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose') 
, Schema = mongoose.Schema 
, Collection = mongoose.Collection;


var taskSchema = mongoose.Schema({
....
});

mongoose.model('Task', taskSchema).remove();

module.exports = mongoose.model('Task', taskSchema);
```

The remove() method seems to not get called. Any pointers as to why this would happen?

Comment: which version of mongoose you are using ?

Comment: "mongoose" : "~3.8.1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to remove document like

```
model.remove({}).exec();
```

Or by using callback

```
model.remove( function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  // Removed
});
```

Refer [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html)